# Как конвертировать SolidColorBrush в Hex?

Tags: c#, color, hex

```
public static string GetHexFromColor(SolidColorBrush Color)
    {
        string hexcolor = "#FFFF0000";
        //argb типа byte конвертировать в hex 
        var a = Color.Color.A;
        var r = Color.Color.R;
        var g = Color.Color.G;
        var b = Color.Color.B;

        //не допустимый термин byte
        BitConverter.ToString( byte[a, r, g, b], 0);


        return hexcolor;
    }
```

Это приводит к странному результату: #FF-80-80-0080-80-0080-0000

```
Byte[] bytes1 = { a, r, g, b };

hexcolor = "#" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes1, 0) + BitConverter.ToString(bytes1, 1) + BitConverter.ToString(bytes1, 2) + BitConverter.ToString(bytes1, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string hexcolor = Color.Color.ToString();
```